# How to convert web methods jar to osgi bundles

Tags: java, jar, apache-camel, osgi, webmethods

I'm using Apache camel with blueprint DSL and I am trying to send messages from my standalone fuse application to webmethods queue but getting the error

**Caused by: javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Unable to find the InitialContextFactory com.webmethods.jms.naming.WmJmsNamingCtxFactory.**

even though I have the required web methods jar in my class path.

I even tried exposing the following jars as bundles

```
jms.jar,
wm-brokerclient.jar,
wm-g11nutils.jar,
wm-jmsclient.jar,
wm-jmsnaming.jar
```

using the command *osgi:install -s file:ProjectDir/target/jarname.jar*

but there is no effect with that. where am I going wrong ?
Is it possible to expose web methods jars as osgi bundle?

Answer (score 0):

Please use below mentioned command for installing jars as bundle .

> osgi:install -s mvn:GROUP_ID/ARTIFACT_ID/VERSION

This worked for me when deploying jars in karaf console.

Comment: I tried this ...But I am unble to expose the webmethods broker jars as bundkes using the above command